# URL changes but page new page is not rendered Ionic React , IonReactRouter with history

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-redux, react-router, ionic-react

I am writing an app using Ionic 5 with React and Redux. I am attempting to navigate to a new page, /tabs/home, upon a successful login attempt. I am trying to do this by pushing the new URL onto the react router history prop when I get a successful response from the backend. This is working in that it changes the url from /login to /tabs/home but the login page is still displayed.

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './helpers/store';
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import CreateBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

export const history = CreateBrowserHistory();

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
             <App />           
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { history } from './index';
import { alertActions } from './actions/alert.actions';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  IonApp,
} from '@ionic/react';
import { IonReactRouter } from '@ionic/react-router';
import { LoginPage } from './pages/Login';

import MainTabs from './pages/MainTabs';

function App() {
  const alert = useSelector(state => state.alert);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    history.listen((location, action) => {
      console.log(location);
      console.log(action);
      dispatch(alertActions.clear());
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <IonApp>
        {/*
         // @ts-ignore*/}
        <IonReactRouter history={history}>
          <Route path="/tabs" component={MainTabs} />
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
        </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Login.tsx

```
function LoginPage() {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    username: '',
    password: ''
  });
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const { username, password } = inputs;
  const loggingIn = useSelector(state => state.authentication.loggingIn);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(userActions.logout());
  }, []);

  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setInputs(inputs => ({ ...inputs, [name]: value }));
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     setSubmitted(true);
     if (username && password) {
       dispatch(userActions.login(username, password));
     }
  }

  return (
    <IonPage id="login-page">
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonButtons slot="start">
            <IonMenuButton></IonMenuButton>
          </IonButtons>
          <IonTitle>Login</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent>

        <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <IonList>
            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel position="stacked" color="primary">Username</IonLabel>
              <IonInput name="username" type="text" value={username} spellCheck={false} autocapitalize="off" onIonChange={handleChange} className={'form-control' + (submitted && !username ? ' is-invalid' : '')} required>
              </IonInput>
            </IonItem>

            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel position="stacked" color="primary">Password</IonLabel>
              <IonInput name="password" type="password" value={password} onIonChange={handleChange} className={'form-control' + (submitted && !password ? ' is-invalid' : '')} required>
              </IonInput>
            </IonItem>

          </IonList>

          <IonRow>
            <IonCol>
              {loggingIn && <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>}
              <IonButton type="submit" expand="block">Login</IonButton>
            </IonCol>
            <IonCol>
              <IonButton routerLink="/signup" color="light" expand="block">Signup</IonButton>
            </IonCol>
          </IonRow>
        </form>

      </IonContent>

    </IonPage>
  )
}

export { LoginPage };
```

login action

```
function login(username, password) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request({ username }));

        userService.login(username, password)
        .then(
            user => {
                dispatch(success(user));
                history.push('/tabs/home');
            },
            error => {
                dispatch(failure(error.toString()));
                dispatch(alertActions.error(error.toString()));
            }
        );
    };

    function request(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST, user } }
    function success(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, user } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE, error } }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ISSUE :**

As per the doc :

The `IonReactRouter` component wraps the traditional `BrowserRouter` component from React Router, and sets the app up for routing. Therefore, use `IonReactRouter` in place of `BrowserRouter`. You can pass in any props to `IonReactRouter` and they will be passed down to the underlying `BrowserRouter`.

I think custom `history` is not supported by `BrowserRouter`, as you can see [`BrowserRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) supports this props, there no `history` props there

```
basename
forceRefresh
getUserConfirmation
keyLength
children
```

`history` props is available for [`Router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router)

[Issue on github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/20297#issuecomment-578467611)

---

**SOLUTION :**

So I've made below changes for using custom history and it's working

---

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./helpers/store";

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

---

App.tsx

```
    <IonApp>
      <Router history={history}>
        {/* <IonReactRouter history={history}> */}
        <Route path="/tabs" component={MainTabs} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={LoginPage} />
        {/* </IonReactRouter> */}
      </Router>
    </IonApp>
```

---

**OR**

You can use something like this as hack, **[ref](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/20297#issuecomment-625445957)**

```
import React from 'react'
import { History } from 'history'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router'

// Add custom property 'appHistory' to the global window object
declare global {
  interface Window { appHistory: History }
}

const MyApp: React.FC = () => {
  // Store the history object globally so we can access it outside of React components
  window.appHistory = useHistory()

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added the IonRouterOutlet tag in but it didnt change anything as far as I can tell.

Comment: Is it possible create a sample demo over snack expo?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ionic-react-tutorial-router-tabs-9bmrj?file=/src/pages/Login.tsx

Comment: @Stalfurion, Found the issue and also updated answer, please have a look

Comment: @Stalfurion, Glad to know,it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Just put the `exact` attribute in the Route to solve this

```
 <Route path="/tabs" exact component={MainTabs} />
 <Route path="/login" exact component={LoginPage} />
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me, but thank you for the suggestion. It is still updating the URL but not rendering the new page.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have

```
<Route path "/tabs" component={MainTabs} />
```

When instead it should be

```
<Route path "/tabs/home" component={MainTabs} />
```

When you're trying to push your history with `/tabs/home` there is no route specified for that, so it won't know where to go.

Also in your index file I would recommend having an additional route like so

```
<Route exact path "/tabs" component={SomeComponent} />
<Route path "/tabs/home" component={MainTabs} />
```

Just in case you plan on having more than one path attached to your `/tabs` route.

Comment: The route for /tabs/home is in the MainTabs component and there is a redirect there from /tabs to /tabs/home. I may be wrong on this but I think even if it was an issue with not being able to find the route it should still attempt to render a new page not just stay on the current page