# Page is not rendering after using `history.push` in Ionic/React with `IonTabs` as nested routes

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router, ionic-react, ionic-tabs

I have an Ionic/React v5.0.7 app with `IonReactRouter` to manage routing:

```js
// App.tsx

return (
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter history={history}>
      <IonRouterOutlet>
        <Route exact path={ROUTES.HOME} component={Home} />
        <Route exact path={ROUTES.LOGIN} component={Login} />
        <Route path={ROUTES.CONTRACTOR} component={ContractorDashboard} />
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
)
```

In one of my routes (`path={ROUTES.CONTRACTOR}`) I'm trying to implement `IonTabs` which needs to have its own `IonRouterOutlet`, so I have the tabs as nested routes like so:

```js
// ContractorDashboard.tsx

<IonContent>
  <IonTabs>
    <IonTabBar slot="top">
      <IonTabButton href="/contractor/overview" tab="contractor-overview">
        <IonLabel>{t('ContractorDashboard.contractorOverview')}</IonLabel>
      </IonTabButton>
      <IonTabButton href="/contractor/contractor-configs" tab="contractor-configs">
        <IonLabel>{t('ContractorDashboard.contractorConfig')}</IonLabel>
      </IonTabButton>
      <IonTabButton href="/contractor/workers-management" tab="workers-management">
        <IonLabel>{t('ContractorDashboard.workersManagement')}</IonLabel>
      </IonTabButton>
      <IonTabButton href="/contractor/email-responses" tab="email-responses">
        <IonLabel>Some label</IonLabel>
      </IonTabButton>
    </IonTabBar>

    <IonRouterOutlet>
      <Route path="/contractor/contractor-configs" render={() => <ContractorConfigs userId={authUser.uid} />} />
      <Route path="/contractor/workers-management" component={WorkersManagement} />
      <Route path="/contractor/email-responses" render={() => <EmailResponses userId={authUser.uid} />} />
      <Route path="/contractor/contractor-overview" render={() => <IonTitle>Title</IonTitle>} />
      <Route exact path="/contractor" render={() => <Redirect to="/contractor/overview" />} />
    </IonRouterOutlet>
          
  </IonTabs>
</IonContent>
```

Everything works fine until I try to create dynamic navigation to `/contractor` route, which is the root of the tabs' router, using `history.push('/contractor')` or `<Redirect to="/contractor" />`.

In my login component I want to redirect automatically to the `ContractorDashboard` if a user is authenticated. I.e. after a successful login the user should be redirected to the dashboard. I implemented the following:

```js
// Login.tsx

useEffect(() => {
  if (authUser) {
    history.push('/contractor')
  }
}, [authUser, history])
```

What happens is the URL is changed in the address bar but the login page is still visible instead of the `ContractorDashboard`. I also tried this:

```js
// Login.tsx

if (authUser) {
  return <Redirect to="/contractor"/>
}

return (
// ...
)
```

The result is the same. I can see the contractor page in the dev tools but it's not rendered.
A few notes though:

- The result is a bit different when I try different things, like pushing to `/contractor/overview` insted of just `/contractor`. Then the contractor dashboard is visible for a sec and then it's the login page again.
- Sometimes I do get the dashboard, but the tabs are not visible. Its in the DOM and the cursor events are there but still not visible.
- Everything was working before using `IonTabs` in the dashboard.
- What's weird is that when I try to navigate to the login page via the address bar with an authenticated user I'm redirected to the dashboard like I should and everything is working.

I did try replacing `IonReactRouter` with `Router` from `react-router` like suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62421055/url-changes-but-page-new-page-is-not-rendered-ionic-react-ionreactrouter-with). Then redirecting from the login page works but the tabs trigger a full page refresh on every tab change, which is just awful UX.

Here is my `ionic info` output:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI : 6.11.0

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v12.18.3
   npm    : 6.14.6
   OS     : Windows 10
```

and here's my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "application",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.6",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.4.6",
    "@ionic/react": "^5.0.7",
    "@ionic/react-router": "^5.0.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^8.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.25",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.24",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "firebase": "^8.2.3",
    "i18next": "^19.8.4",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.0.22",
    "ionicons": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-localstorage-simple": "^2.3.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "3.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "appium": "appium --chromedriver-executable C:\\Users\\Ori\\code\\chromedrivers\\chromedriver-83-0-4103.exe",
    "e2e:android": "protractor e2e/android-e2e.conf.js",
    "e2e:web": "protractor e2e/web-e2e.conf.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.15",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.8",
    "appium": "^1.20.2",
    "jasmine": "^3.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^6.0.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

So is there a way to properly implement this and how?
Please let me know if any info or code is missing here.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Update**
So for anyone who is interested, I gave up looking for a solution. Instead I implemented my own basic tabs, without routes (never understood why tabs require routing anyway...).
Disregarding styles it's very simple:

```js
const [tab, setTab] = useState<number>(0);
const mapTabs = [
  'contractorOverview',
  'contractorConfigs',
  'workersManagement',
  'emailResponses'
]

const handleTabChange = () => {
  switch (tab) {
    case 0: return <h3>Overview</h3>;
    case 1: return authUser && <ContractorConfigs userId={authUser.uid} />;
    case 2: return <WorkersManagement />;
    case 3: return authUser && <EmailResponses userId={authUser.uid} />;
    default: return <h3>Overview</h3>;
  }
}

return (
  // ....
  <IonContent>
    <IonToolbar color="secondary">
      <IonButtons slot="start">
        {mapTabs.map((_tab, tabIdx) => (
          <IonButton
            key={tabIdx}
            id={`${_tab}`}
            onClick={() => setTab(tabIdx)}
            disabled={mapTabs[tab] === _tab}
          >
            {t(`ContractorDashboard.${_tab}`)}
          </IonButton>
        ))}
      </IonButtons>
    </IonToolbar>

    {handleTabChange()}

  </IonContent>
  // ....
)
```

And that's all you need to have a working tab view (again, without some styling it won't look so nice).
If someone has a solution to the tabs issue (actually I'm not 100% sure what caused the problem... I wasn't able to reproduce in stackblitz...) I would love to hear it.
If not I will post this as an answer...

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I have used `history` and useIonRouter, and I get the same result: url changes correctly, component/page stays the same. All searches on this problem end the same: "use history.push(...)" which is a non-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
history.push({ pathname: '/contractor' })
```

or

```
history.push({ pathname: '/contractor/overview' });
```

Comment: I did, basically one of the above mentioned results, most likely will take me to the dashboard but the tabs won't be visible.

Answer (score 0):

did you try...

```
history.push('/contractor/overview')
```

can you post a small project on stackblitz or codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Having a  component at the root of the pages I'm navigating to fixed my issue. See https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/19622

Comment: Copy the important portions of your link to supplement your answer, link-only answers are against the guidelines of Stack Overflow :)