# In React/Ionic, how do I force my component to render when history.push is called (or rather when my URL changes)?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, routes, render, history

I'm building an Ionic 7 and a REact 18 application.  I have this component with a submit button that pushes a route onto the history object (meant to hcange the URL) when a user clicks the Submit button

```
const OrderItemRecipientComponent: React.FC = () => {
    ...
  const history = useHistory();
  const [isButtonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    // This effect will run after the component re-renders
    if (isButtonDisabled) {
      // move on to the payment
      history.push("/payment");
    }
  }, [isButtonDisabled, history]);
  

  const handleSaveAndContinue = () => {
    setButtonDisabled(true); // Disable the button

    // add the item to the cart
    addToCart(orderItem);
  };

  return (
    <>
    ...
      <p>
        <AddressForm
          contactInfo={contactInfo}
          setContactInfo={setContactInfo}
        />
      </p>
      <IonButton expand="full" onClick={handleSaveAndContinue}  disabled={isButtonDisabled}>
        Pay
      </IonButton>
    </>
  );
};

export default OrderItemRecipientComponent;
```

and then I have this defined in my App.tsx routes

```
  <IonContent className="ion-padding" scroll-y>
    <IonRouterOutlet>
        ...
      <Route exact path="/payment">
        <PaymentContainer />
      </Route>
    </IonRouterOutlet>
  </IonContent>
</IonReactRouter>
```

THe issue is that often when I click the "Pay" button, although I see the route in my URL changes, I don't always see the PaymentContainer component rendered (the original compnent remains).  When I click "Refresh" on my browser, I do see the correct component rendered.  How can I correct my sequence so that the PaymentContainer component alawys renders when my route changes?

Comment: Do u use useNavigate from react-router-dom to change the location on Submit?

Comment: I'm using "history.push("/payment");" to attempt to change to the new route.  I tried putting that in my submit click handler and it did no good.  I then tried putting it in a side effect (as seen in my question) and that also did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [joshua-wyllie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20208959/joshua-wyllie)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74021623/11103139) which mentions this [github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/19622): you need to have a wrapping `<IonPage>` on each of your pages (in your case as the root of `PaymentContainer`).

If that doesn't solve the issue, you can try this as a workaround:
As [yairopro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4170935/yairopro) mentions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53837442/11103139), you can try forcing an update like this:

```js
const history = useHistory();
const [, forceUpdate] = useReducer(x => x + 1, 0);

useEffect(() => {
  // This effect will run after the component re-renders
  if (isButtonDisabled) {
    // move on to the payment
    history.push("/payment");
    forceUpdate();
  }
}, [isButtonDisabled, history]);
```

Comment: The correct answer, Dave must use `useEffect` and a `forceUpdate` trick to do the re-render, But I think you should add a single like to explain where the `history` comes from.